# Deferred initialization "proxy" in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, generic-programming

Let's suppose I have an object tree, with objects from a (quite large) set of classes; classes more or less under my control (and say, each implementing `IBaseInterface`, for semantic typing).
The tree is normally filled in a depth-first manner. At times, however, the nodes must be created at a different location in the execution flow; hence I need something that can act as a placeholder (proxy-like) for the objects. The placeholder should hold a reference to where it was created, without any other interference with the underlying type/object (decorator-style).

I was thinking of something similar to

```
interface IPlaceholder
{
    PositionReference RealLocation { get; }
}

class Placeholder<T> : T, IPlaceholder
{
    PositionReference RealLocation { get; private set; }
}
```

However, this wouldn't work since C# cannot have generic classes inheriting from their type parameters.

A brute-force approach would be, of course, to dynamically generate classes at runtime to specification; but this seems a bit too extreme (and cumbersome if I have to fiddle with Reflection.Emit manually).

What would be the best approach to create such placeholder objects?

(Extra note: This is pretty much like `Lazy<T>`, except that the object is normally expected to be of the original type; when not, the proxied object cannot be constructed before the parent node is processed.)

Comment: What do you mean by a different location? is it the depth (level) in the tree? which parent it has? can you please explain more?

Comment: Concrete example for different location: The tree is generated from a stream, LL-parser style. The stream (sometimes) has tokens for nodes whose data is at a different location in the stream.No seeking information is in the tokens, and the tree generation cannot continue without parsing the token. Hence the proxied node data is matched after building the tree.

Answer (score 0):

What you're after is a *virtual proxy*. Here is a simple example. Suppose you have a `Bitmap` class that loads eagerly:

```
interface IBitmap { void Draw(); }
class Bitmap : IBitmap
{
  Bitmap(string filename)
  {
    WriteLine($"Loading bitmap from {filename}");
  }
  void Draw()
  {
    WriteLine($"Drawing bitmap!");
  }
}
```

A virtual proxy is a wrapper that doesn't load bitmap until needed:

```
class VirtualBitmap : IBitmap
{
  private Bitmap bitmap;
  private string filename;
  public VirtualBitmap(string filename)
  {
    this.filename = filename;
  }
  void Draw()
  {
    if (bitmap == null) bitmap = new Bitmap(filename);
    bitmap.Draw();
  }
}
```

Feel free to use `Lazy<T>` instead.